# how to pass password in mysql command line

Tags: python, mysql

I've a password with special characters in it, something like this `eu8y~!~LZVdzW!2A`.

Whenever, I try to fire the mysqldump command, it throws an error saying

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

this is how I do it.

```
mysqldump -uroot -p'eu8y~!~LZVdzW!2A' db_name > db.sql
```

however, if provide the password separately, it works.

```
mysqldump -uroot -p db_name > db.sql
```

I run the above command in python. How can I do it?

Comment: Try: `mysqldump -uroot -peu8y~!~LZVdzW!2A db_name > db.sql`. Remember specifying a password on the command line should be considered insecure, see [7.1.2.1 End-User Guidelines for Password Security](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html).

Comment: Have already tried this. Does not works.

Comment: _"I run the above command in python."_ - [_then show the exact way you run it_](/help/mcve), or we can't help you if the problem happens to be in the difference between what you have shown and what you actually use. It's strange that I have to tell this to a 2.5k+ user.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem:

```sql
mysql> CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'eu8y~!~LZVdzW!2A';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL ON `db_name`.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

```bsh
$ mysqldump -umyuser -p'eu8y~!~LZVdzW!2A' db_name > db.sql
```

The file (`db.sql`) is generated as expected.